# Workaround for generic return

Tags: c#, generics

I have following class

> ```
> public abstract class Rule
>     {
>         protected Rule()
>         {
>             Nodes = new List<Node>();
>         }
>         public List<Node> Nodes { get; private set; }
>         public int NumberOfElements { get; set; }
>
>         public abstract Result<Rule> Validate(IEnumerable<Node> validUnits);
>
>     }
> ```

now, also i have :

> ```
> public class MinNumberOfCredits : Rule
> {
>
>    public override string ToString()
>     {
>         return string.Format(NumberOfElements);
>     }
>
>     public override Result<Rule> Validate(IEnumerable<Node> validUnits)
>     {
>         var totalCredits = validUnits.Sum(x => x.Credits);
>         return NumberOfElements > totalCredits ? new Result<MinNumberOfCredits>(ResultMessage.Fail, NumberOfElements) : new Result<MinNumberOfCredits>();
>     }
> }
> ```

the problem is that my return type is `Result<Rule>` but in specific class i must return `Result<MinNumberOfCredits>`.

Comment: Why do you need to return Result<MinNumberOfCredits>?

Comment: why can't you change return type to `Result<MinNumberOfCredits>`?

Comment: Because Result<MinNumberOfCredits> and Result<Rule> are different things , in base class i have only base rule.

Comment: I need generic to use internally `typeof` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you cannot have methods having the same name and parameters but different return types, so what you have in mind does just not work. There a various possible approaches to solve your problem, but they depend on your exact use case:

- Make `Rule` a generic type `Rule<T>` and change the return type of `Validate` to `Result<T>`.
- Extract commonialities of `Result<Rule>` and `Result<MinNumberOfCredits>` into an interface and return that one.
- ...

I'm aware that all of those solutions will require further modifications. I just wanted to give you a direction to go.